# Error when I tried to apply filter in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of objects, and I wanted to filter it based on a specific string property.

```
 openTasks: Task[]; //Initial list
 inProgressTasks: Task[] = []; //Filtered list

getTasks(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.projectId = +params.get('projectId');

      if (this.projectId === 0) {
        this.taskService.getTasks().subscribe(tasks => this.openTasks = tasks); 
        // HERE I ACQUIRE LIST OF OPEN TASKS
      } else {
        this.taskService.getTaskByProjectId(this.projectId).subscribe(tasks => this.openTasks = tasks);
       // HERE I ACQUIRE LIST OF OPEN TASKS
      }

      // FILTER
      this.inProgressTasks = this.openTasks.filter(task => task.state === 'IN_PROGRESS');

    });
  }
```

I received this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Could you, please, help me with this error?

Comment: are you sure this.openTasks is not empty or null ?

Comment: yes, I'm very sure.

Comment: I tried to do that but the same result :)

Comment: Did you check your response?

Comment: Could you paste the entire code written in this file?

Comment: @Mridul I tried to put a console. log after filter, to see what it is in the filter list
this.inProgressTasks = this.openTasks.filter(task => task.state === 'IN_PROGRESS');
        console.log('Tasks in progress: ' + JSON.stringify(this.inProgressTasks));

Comment: But I received instant error. It doesn't print event "Tasks in progress"

Comment: @abc please paste the entire code in your file

Comment: This is a typical misunderstanding when working with async code and data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probably having problems here because of the async nature with which you fetch openTasks.

Try waiting for it to definitely finish before trying to filter it.

```
getTasks(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.projectId = +params.get('projectId');

      if (this.projectId === 0) {
        this.taskService.getTasks().subscribe(tasks => 
            {this.openTasks = tasks},
            error => {},
            () => { this.filterTasks()}
        );         
      } 

    });
  }
```

```
filterTasks() {
    this.inProgressTasks = this.openTasks.filter(task => task.state === 'IN_PROGRESS');
}
```

Comment: Now it's working, thank you! The problem was async.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `this.openTasks` is not set yet. it is only set after the `this.openTasks = tasks` in `subscribe`. this should work.

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.projectId = +params.get('projectId');

      if (this.projectId === 0) {
        this.taskService.getTasks()
                  .subscribe(tasks => {
                           this.openTasks = tasks;
                           // your code that requirest openTasks
                           this.inProgressTasks = this.openTasks.filter(task => task.state === 'IN_PROGRESS');
                           });
      } else {
        this.taskService.getTaskByProjectId(this.projectId)
                        .subscribe(tasks => {
                           this.openTasks = tasks
                           // your code that requirest openTasks
                           this.inProgressTasks = this.openTasks.filter(task => task.state === 'IN_PROGRESS');
                         });
      }
    });
```